# Нужно вывести максимальный и минимальный из введенных массивов. Но выводит только макс, а мин = 0

Tags: c, массивы

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>

int main(){


    int arr[100],n;
    int i;
    int max = arr[0];
    int min = arr[0];
    printf("Количество единиц: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Массив с индексом %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(min > arr[i])
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Max: %d\nMin: %d", max, min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Намек: чему равно min после строчки ``int min = arr[0];``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь строчки

```
int max = arr[0];
int min = arr[0];
```

после цикла, где вводятся данные.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сработало.